# Automatically Filter DataTable

Tags: c#

I have a console application connected to a SQL Server database with several tables and views. To get the entire table I so something like:

```
myAppDataset dsTemp = new myAppDataset();
myAppDataset.AppLogDataTable dtLog = dsTemp.AppLog;
myAppDataset.AppUserDataTable dtUser = dsTemp.AppUser;
```

Then when I need to filter I create a DataView:

```
DataView dvLog = dtLog.DefaultView;
dvLog.RowFilter = "DeptID = 1";
DataView dvUser = dtUser.DefaultView;
dvUser.RowFilter = "DeptID = 1";
```

That all works fine.

What I'd like to know is if there is a way modify the DataSet (or something else) so that I don't need to create the DataViews? In other words, I want every AppLogDataTable, AppUserDataTable, etc that gets created to be filtered for DeptID = 1. Essentially what I want to achieve is to be able to pass a parameter to my data class constructor that will automatically filter all of the data tables so that when they are used I don't have to worry about creating a DataView and filtering the table every time (which also necessitates the passing of the original filtering parameters).

I tried creating a DataView and overwriting the original object, but got an error that the DataTable couldn't be casted or something to that effect:

```
myAppDataset dsTemp = new myAppDataset();
myAppDataset.AppLogDataTable dtLog = dsTemp.AppLog;
DataView dvLog = dtLog.DefaultView;
dvLog.RowFilter = "DeptID = 1";
dtLog = (myAppDataset.AppLogDataTable)dvLog.ToTable();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't use a DataSet or DataTable or DataView anymore. We're in 2017, let's use strongly typed objects instead.

Comment: @mason how should you do in 2017 without a DataSet with an Access database, or another oldeb\odbc db?

Comment: Strongly typed objects, like I said in my last comment. Something like `List<MyCustomType>`.

Comment: @mason but you need code to fill the list. and some logic for know  if an item added, modified or deleted. ect. in other words you need a dataset.

Comment: @lomed Yes, you need code to fill the list. That could mean reading in data from an [IDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) or using a Micro ORM such as [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) to fill it. As far as adding, modifying, deleting you would have commands specifically to handle those in your application, that's how you know. Again, you don't need a DataSet, DataTable, or DataView. It's 2017. We've learned to use far better tools to accomplish the job. Don't object to it, just figure out how to use it.

Comment: @mason, thank. thank also for the Daper link!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147994/discussion-between-lomed-and-mason).

Comment: @mason Thanks for the suggestion, but the application is already developed and I'm trying to find the most cost effective way to implement an enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

some possible suggestions:

### use Linq2Object, and not DataView at all

```
var filterStep1 = dtUser.Where(x => x.DeptID == 1);
var filterStep2 = filterStep1.Where(x => x.XYZ < 40);
Console.WriteLine(filterStep2);
```

is equivalent to:

```
var filter = dtUser.Where(x => x.DeptID == 1 && x => x.XYZ < 40);
Console.WriteLine(filter);
```

### edit the sql query

you can filter in the sql query.

in TypedDataSet case, double-click on `myAppDataset` in the solution-explorer, click on the `Fill, GetData()` that appears under the table-box.

in property window (F4), click double-click on `Select Command` property. the query-designer shown. add the filter to query (if you not want write the `1` but parameter, type `?` in the criteria - it create parameter for command automaticaly).

### use List for criteria

another solution is create a list of criteria, and join them to RowFilter:

```
var criteria = new List<string>();
criteria.Add("DeptID = 1");
criteria.Add("XYZ < 40");
dvUser.RowFilter = string.Join(" AND ", criteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be reading data from the database if you don't intend to use it. Filter your SQL query.

```
select somecolumns from sometable where DeptID = 1
```

However, let's pretend for a moment that you're reading all the data into memory for caching purposes or something like this. Don't put that into a DataSet, DataTable, or DataView. Those are outdated constructs. They're slow, inefficient, and give you none of the benefits of binding to a strongly typed object.

Instead, create a type to represent your data. Since you don't give much context, I'm going to pretend you're dealing with Students that have a many to one relationship with Departments.

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
}
```

Now you have some choices. You can use ADO.NET to get the data.

```
public class StudentSqlServerRepository
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public StudentSqlServerRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public List<Student> GetStudentsByDepartmentId(int departmentId)
    {
        var students = new List<Student>();

        using(var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        using(var command = new SqlCommand("select Id, Name, DepartmentId from students where DepartmentId = @DepartmentId", connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("DepartmentId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = departmentId);
            connection.Open();

            using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    var student = new Student();
                    student.Id = (int)reader["Id"];
                    student.Name = (string)reader["Name"];
                    student.DepartmentId = (int)reader["DepartmentId"];
                    students.Add(student);
                }                
            }
        }

        return students;
    }        
}
```

But that's a lot of yucky code. Fortunately, [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper), a micro ORM, can make this a lot cleaner.

```
public class StudentSqlServerRepository
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public StudentSqlServerRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public List<Student> GetStudentsByDepartmentId(int departmentId)
    {    
        using(var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            var students = connection.Query<Student>("select Id, Name, DepartmentId from students where DepartmentId = @DepartmentId", new { DepartmentId = departmentId}).AsList();
            return students;
        }           
    }        
}
```

Now getting your students is as easy as

```
var studentRepository = new StudentSqlServerRepository(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StudentDatabase"].ConnectionString);
var students = studentRepository.GetStudentsByDepartmentId(1);

//let's pretend this is Web Forms and we want to bind to a control
StudentsGridView.DataSource = students;
StudentsGridView.DataBind();

//let's pretend it's MVC and we want to return a View
return View(students);
```

Compare the memory usage, amount of network traffic, query execution time, and overall ease of this approach as opposed to using a DataTable and filtering in memory.